# Python: non greedy before or after

Tags: python, extract, greedy, non-greedy

***I made a few tests to help myself to understand non-greedy in Python, but it made me much more confused than before. Thank you for the help!***

```
lan='From 000@hhhaaa@stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za@bbb@ccc fff@ddd eee'
print(re.findall('\S+@\S+?',lan))          # 1
print(re.findall('\S+@\S+',lan))           # 2
print(re.findall('\S+?@\S+?',lan))         # 3
print(re.findall('\S+?@\S+',lan))          # 4
```

Result:

```
['000@hhhaaa@stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za@bbb@c', 'fff@d']                   # 1
['000@hhhaaa@stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za@bbb@ccc', 'fff@ddd']               # 2
['000@h', 'hhaaa@s', 'tephen.marquard@u', 'ct.ac.za@b', 'bb@c', 'fff@d']   # 3
['000@hhhaaa@stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za@bbb@ccc', 'fff@ddd']               # 4
```

Question:

1. why result only shows one d here - @d?
2. is normal, very clear.
3. very confusing, I even do not know how to ask the logic behind... Especially when compared with 1...
4. it seems it is same as 2, so why ? before @ is so 'weak'?

Comment: The lazy `\S+?` has to match at least a single char due to the `+`. If there is nothing following the pattern, it will match just a single char as is it lazy. In case there is an `@`, it will match as least as possible chars until it matches the first occurrence of `@` Perhaps this page can be helpful http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti  *I believe python's re module has the same behaviour as any other software that uses regex.* That is quite incorrect. There are multiple dialects of regular expressions. Even Python supports two (`re` and `regex`).

Comment: But then again, all the regex dialects that support non-greedy matching work exactly the same for the question asked there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why result only shows one d here - @d?

Because `+?` is not required to match more than once, so it doesn't.

> 2. is normal, very clear.
> 3. very confusing, I even do not know how to ask the logic behind... Especially when compared with 1...

Again, `+?` matches as many characters **as it has to** - as opposed to matching as many characters **as it can**, which is exactly the difference between greedy and non-greedy matching.

On the example of `\S+?@\S+?` matching `From 000@hhhaaa@stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za@bbb@ccc`:

- it matches the `From`, but then it fails because there is a space.
- it matches the `000`, then the `@` matches, then `\S+?` *again* matches as many `\S` as it has to. It **has to** match 1 character.
- the overall match is `000@h`.

> 4. it seems it is same as 2, so why ? before @ is so 'weak'?

Explained above.

---

Since email addresses can't contain spaces, why bother with non-greedy matching anyway? You could use something as simple as `\S+@\S+`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation! I just studied non-greedy part, so I wanted to do some tests to see if I understood clearly. Luckily I did these tests! Now I understand! I also thought Python was going to read from @ to left hand side for the part before @, actually I realise now Python reads from left to right!!! Thanks!